# GPPSignInButton is not firing it's action method

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, button

I have a `GPPSignInButton` in a storyboard view, to authenticate the user via Google Plus ,i linked its `touchUpInside` event to a callback method, it works on iPhone perfectly, but when i tried to test it on the iPAD on a scale of 2x and 1x ,it never get called !! and App store rejects the binary for this reason .

i really hitting my head to the wall .. any help will be appreciated

Comment: can u show your rejection type

Comment: We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.4 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.

The user was unable to access via Google+.

The steps to reproduce are:

1) Launch the app
2) Tap on Google+ icon
3) No login screen is presented

This scenario works great on iPhone !